# If else statements, while loop broken

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop, nested

I'd like to preface this with what will become obvious in that I am extremely new to programming and have much to learn. So I'm having a problem where my nested if else statements are being ignored. The second and third "printf" statements are integers but are converted into decimals, since they are the percent discount being applied to the price for medium and large orders. I'm using a while loop to test 3 conditions and if they are all met the message is printed, however if they are not met, I have made 3 if and if else statements to test for which condition is not being met. However , I have missed something as they are not being accurately printed.The base widget cost should not be higher than the base price, med price, or the large price, as this will make the widget sold at a loss. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, besides my confusing names that are too similar.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define widget_cost 0.40

int main (){


float sellprice;
int discount_med;
float discount_med_price;
float med_price;
float large_price;
int discount_large;
float discount_large_price;



    printf("How much are you selling each widget for\n");
        scanf("%f", &sellprice);

    printf("What are you discounting medium orders?\n");
        scanf("%f", &discount_med);

    printf("What are you discounting large orders?\n");
        scanf("%f", &discount_large);

discount_med_price=discount_med/100 * sellprice;
med_price= sellprice-discount_med_price;

discount_large_price=discount_large/100 * sellprice;
large_price=sellprice-discount_large_price;


while  (sellprice>widget_cost && med_price>widget_cost && large_price>widget_cost){   

            printf("All prices look good to me!\n");
            printf("Good luck!\n");
}


  if (widget_cost>sellprice){
        printf("Nick, your base price is too low!");
        printf("Good luck!\n");
}
       else if (widget_cost>med_price){
            printf("Nick, you are discounting medium purchases too much!\n");
            printf("Good luck!\n");
}
           else if (widget_cost>large_price){
                printf("Nick, you are discounting large purchases too much!\n");
                 printf("Goof luck!\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: discount_med is declared of type int, yet you use `%f` in the scanf specifier. Also, division will truncate with an int.

Comment: Do you really need the while loop? If all three conditions are met, you will be printing "All prices look good to me" over an over, since the while condition will never become false and you will be stuck in an infinite loop. I believe you should change this into an if statement.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized this as well, I've changed it to an if statement, since it prints once if all are met.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your 'while' to an 'if'. Otherwise your while will run forever and you won't ever get to the code after that while statement. While means "as long as the condition is true, repeat this action," and you don't want it to repeat.

You should also change all of your 'else if' to just 'if' since from your description you want Nick to know of all pricing points that lose money. So if med_price and sell price are both too low, you want to print both warning statements, not just the first one. Else if cases will never be seen if a prior if or else if condition was met.

And one other thing... Since you do a 'printf("good luck!\n")' in all cases, you only need that line once right above your 'return 0'. Delete all the other instances of that statement.

Good luck!

Comment: I've changed the statements to just "if's" however when I test a condition like, base price 2, med discount 80, and large discount 90, I am still getting the first condition met, when it should tell me that the large discount is too big.

Comment: With the above conditions(base price, $2 med discount 80%, and large discount 90%. My med discount is,1.6(80%) off of 2, so $.40, which  is fine, but 90% off mean 1.8(90%) off of a base of $2, which is $.20 which is too low., and should trigger the 4th if statement, Nick you are discounting large purchases too much!. However when I run this in the program, I am triggering the first if statement.

Comment: I would probably not use a #define statement for widget_cost. I would put `float widget_cost = 0.40;` somewhere in your main() like after your other variable declarations.  I can't test this right now but maybe that makes the difference. Maybe you should printf all the values after you do your calculations so you can make sure the values are what you think they are. Like `printf("large_price was%f.\n",large_price);`

Comment: I've put widget as a variable, with a define value of .40 in the int main function, but it still thinks that a 90% (widget cost .20) is acceptable. The formula for finding the price after dicounts correct, it still thinks its acceptable though( anything below .40 , is not acceptable value)

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out.  You have declared two ints - discount_large and discount_med.  When you say `discount_large_price=discount_large/100 * sellprice;` that casts the result to an int, not a float, because an int divided by an int equals an int. Either change the declaration of discount_large and discount_med to type float instead of int, or change the 100 to 100.0.  If either of the two values are float, then the result will be a float also.